# The best way to calculate percentage in this case

Tags: mysql

I have a comments table where I store the comment content, author id and there is also one field that can only be whether 1 or 0 (if it's 1 this is a best comment on the post). What I want to do is to count the percentage of best comments in whole comments of the specific user by it's id. The only way that comes in my mind is to make two mysql queries - first count the best comments, then count total comments and then calculate the percentage, but I believe there is a better way to do this, using one mysql query... Is there any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have not stated your table schema, but you can do something like this:

```
SELECT customer, (SUM(best) / COUNT(comment_id)) * 100 AS percentage_best
FROM comments
GROUP BY customer;
```

As the `best` field is 1 or 0, summing the column will give the number of `best` comments, then you can just count the rest.

For a specific customer you can of course omit the `GROUP BY` and the initial field and add a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT (SUM(best) / COUNT(comment_id)) * 100 AS percentage_best
FROM comments
WHERE customer = 123;
```

Hopefully you have an `INDEX` on the `customer` field in that `comments` table in either case.

Comment: SUM(best) could you please explain this part in more details?

Comment: @Levani: There is a useful side-effect of having `BOOLEAN` variables represented by `1` and `0` in MySQL.  They can act as integers.  If you summate a boolean variable (`SUM(flag)`), the total is the number of true records, ie. the number of fields containing `1` as each `TRUE` value counts once, each `FALSE` value counts zero.  This is used here to get the total number of `TRUE` votes, equivalent to: `... COUNT(best) ... WHERE best = 1`